# Trouble using nginx location block to exclude certain files from fastcgi cache

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, block

I've searched and tried lots of iterations of an nginx location block to exclude certain files from the fastcgi cache, but I can't get it to work. I understand using a location block is preferable to an if statement, which is why I'm trying to do it this way. I want to exclude certain .php files from being cached. I have tried many iterations of this sort of thing, but to no avail:

```
location  ^(reports|purge|renewalemail|renewalcriteria).php$ {
    set $skip_cache 1;
}
```

I have also tried using a map directive outside the server block:

```
map $request_uri $skip_cache {
    # Enable caching in general
    default 0;
    # disable it for these URLs
    "/log/" 1;
    "~*/login.php" 1;
    # or use regular expressions
    "/(reports|purge|renewalemail|renewalcriteria|login)\.php$" 1;
}
```

I've tried many different versions of the above, eg, no regex, like `"/login.php" 1;` or `"login.php" 1;`, but no luck. Ultimately, I'd like to use the bottom line to include all the php files I want to skip the cache on, but I am trying to get a simpler line to work first.

What am I doing wrong? How can I exclude these files (which are in the root folder)? Thanks for any help.